# Retrieve all columns from table A and some from table B using laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel

I am trying to retrieve the thumb image path by joining the images table to the listing table. As such, I have the following query in my controller.

```
$listings = Listing::select('listings.*, images.path as image_path')
    ->where('listings.ownerid', '=', $ownerid)
    ->leftJoin('images', 'listings.thumbId', '=', 'images.id')->get();
```

After testing out the function, the query fails since laravel interprets the query as

```
select `listings`.`*, images`.`path` as `image_path` from `listings` left join `images` on `listings`.`thumbId` = `images`.`id` where `listings`.`ownerid` = 1)
```

Notice the asterisk (*) is joined with the ", images" word making it `'*, images'`.

The query works fine without laravel's odd typo. How does one fix this issue?

Comment: try `select('listings.*, images.*, images.path as image_path')`

Comment: It results to an SQL syntax error.

Comment: I have also tried adding backticks and single quotes to before and after the periods but the issue still persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do one change in your query. You are passing raw select fields so you need to use `selectRaw()` instead of `select()`. Like

```
$listings = Listing::selectRaw('listings.*, images.path as image_path')
    ->where('listings.ownerid', '=', $ownerid)
    ->leftJoin('images', 'listings.thumbId', '=', 'images.id')->get();
```

check by try above query.

Comment: @Captain your well come. It will be very good if you mark that answer as helpful. mark checked to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `Laravel Eloquent` Relationships feature. Since your code above is more like Query Builder rather than Eloquent. Let's see the example bellow:

You will have 2 Models, 1 for each table (`listings`, `images`):

**App\Listing** Model:

```
<?php
...
use App\Image;
class Listing extends Eloquent {
    ...
    protected $table = 'listings';

    // define Eloquent Relationship of Listing model to Image model
    public function image() {
       return $this->belongsTo(Image::class, 'thumbId');
    }
    ...
}
```

**App\Image** Model:

```
<?php
...
use App\Listing;
class Image extends Eloquent {
    ...
    protected $table = 'images';

    ...
    // define Eloquent Relationship of Image model to Listing model
    public function listings() {
        return $this->hasMany(Listing::class, 'thumbId');
    }

}
```

So how to get the data?

```
// get all listing data
$listings = Listing::all();

// loop through the data
foreach ($listing as $listing) {
    dump($listing->id);

    // because we have define the relationship, we can access the related data of image
    dump($listing->image->path);

    // call $this->image will return related Image model
    dump($listing->image);
}
```

You can see Laravel [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships) for more example and explanation.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, it's working now. Also your explanation makes everything clear. I'll try looking more into the relationships feature.